# ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE ASC not functioning as expected

Tags: mysql, database, sql-order-by, str-to-date

Heres my select query,

```
select rac_username, rac_profilepicture, tafd_postid, tafd_postcontent, tafd_postimage_source, DATE_FORMAT(tafd_postadded,'%M %d, %Y') tafd_postadded,tafd_imotion, (select count(rpg_actormakeget) from r_post_getyou where rpg_postrelate = tafd_postid and rpg_isremoved = 0) as tafd_igetyoucount, (select count(rpg_postrelate) from r_post_getyou where rpg_postrelate = tafd_postid and rpg_actormakeget = (select rac_accountid from r_account_credentials where rac_username = 'zheuswalker' )) as isliked, (select count(rfc_commentid) from r_feeds_comments where rfc_feedparent = tafd_postid) rfc_commentcount from t_account_feeds inner join r_account_credentials on r_account_credentials.rac_accountid = t_account_feeds.tafd_postcreator  
ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE (tafd_postadded,'%M %d, %Y') ASC
```

I already, tried ordering the date by desc, but still i dont get the expected result. I want that the date will be sorted in ascending order (Latest to Oldest).

I tried also ordering it by this (  ORDER BY tafd_postadded asc ) and [see picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kVZHs.jpg), notice that March 2019 is in between June 2018, November 2018

Comment: That is one off the reasons why you should use native DATE datatype instead off CHAR or VARCHAR to store dates and convert it with `STR_TO_DATE(..)`

Comment: *"...in ascending order (latest to oldest)..."* Ascending date order is *earliest* (oldest) to *latest* (and the dates in your first screenshot are in that order). "latest to oldest" would be *descending*.

Comment: The order seems right  .. you have a date asc  so  what your goal ???

Comment: @RaymondNijland - It's June **2018** and March **2019** in the first screenshot. (We can ignore the second, which is sorted lexicographically.)

Comment: @RaymondNijland   .  i  see march 01,2019  after january  10, 2019 ..  could be we are lloking to different image

Comment: T.J.Crowder and scaisEdge never mind i didn't notice the records contains multiple years also.

Comment: So just to clear this question, the first image was ordered by str_to_date , order asc is not working, nothing happes when you add asc or desc at the end. While on the second picture, it was ordered natively, btw, the tafd_postadded was DateTime

Answer (score 0):

STR_TO_DATE compares strings, so it is normal that Mars is before November as letter M is before letter N.

You should do :

```
ORDER BY tafd_postadded DESC
```

Desc for Latest to Oldest
Asc for Oldest to Latest

Comment: Philoupe, i tried that already, see second picture. but still it wasnt sorted just what i want.

Answer (score 0):

Im using **datetime** on my tafd_postadded column, so when sorting datetime we should use `UNIX_TIMESTAMP();`

```
select * from table order by UNIX_TIMESTAMP(datetime column) desc
```